Android (react native) Push notification with Emarsys Service
I receive push messages through Emarsys. The problem is that on Android I don't get the notification in the foreground like banner, I only get it in the notification manager. Is there a way to handle this without a library? With a directory I saw that there is notifee but it causes me to receive 2 messages for every push because now notifee also pushes.
I am currently attaching the information that comes back to me and I receive it and print it in alert.
const App = () => {
    enableFreeze(true);
    const backHandlerRef = useRef();
    const backButtonState = useRef(backButtonStateEnum.DISABLED);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribePushListener = messaging().onMessage(
            async (remoteMessage) => {
                Alert.alert("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
            },
        );
        DeeplinkService.init();
        AppsFlyerAnalyticsService.init();
        GoogleAnalyticsService.init();

        const handleEvent = (eventName, payload) => {
            Alert.alert(`${eventName}: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
        };

        Emarsys.setEventHandler(handleEvent);

        if (phoneUtils.isAndroid()) {
            backHandlerRef.current = BackHandler.addEventListener(
                "hardwareBackPress",
                onBackButtonPressAndroid,
            );
        }

        return () => {
            if (backHandlerRef.current) {
                backHandlerRef.current.remove();
            }
            helpers.fireFunction(unsubscribePushListener);
        };
    }, []);

